# JQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with this piece of functionality I'm trying to have an accordion with tabs inside can any one help me as the second accordion tab doesn't seem to open.

http://thecarbonlist.com/test.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i dont see a function call for .accordion()..

Comment: Why do you have an inline style for one pane and not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot going on here.

I was able to get the basic expected functionality by importing the two .js files listed in the 'view source' [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion), and removing the one that you were using. I also had to remove your 'tabs-accordion.css' file, something in there is causing problems.

Also, had to change your `class="accordion"` to `id="accordion"` and add 

  `$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accordion").accordion();
  });`

to a script in the head of the doc. I think your style-sheets are causing most of the problem.

Comment: Hi Ethan,

I have followed what you said and uploaded the file to http://thecarbonlist.com/test2.html but I can't seem to get it to work as you said you did. What am I doing wrong?